# Syntax error or access violation using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm migrating my local files online and having PHP issues with my db script. Works fine locally (running PHP 5.3.8) but gives me the following errors on my server (PHP 5.3.10)

Without $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in /.../...php on line 108

With $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user '...'@'205.186.180.26' for table 'invited'

Here is my code:

```
class guest {
    public $id;
    public $guest_name;
    public $url_phrase;
}

$guest = new guest;

if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $url_phrase = urldecode($_GET['p']); 
} else if (isset($_POST['p'])) {
    $url_phrase = urldecode($_POST['p']); 
}

if (isset($url_phrase)) {

    try {

    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=myhost.com;dbname=mydbname", "myusername", "mypassword");
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $url_phrase = $DBH->quote($url_phrase);
    $sql = "SELECT id, guest_name, url_phrase FROM mydbname.invited WHERE url_phrase = $url_phrase";

    $stmt = $DBH->query($sql);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new guest);

    $guestNumber = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($guestNumber > 0) {
        etc...  
    }
    if($guestType == "solo") {
        foreach($stmt as $guest) {
            $name = $guest->guest_name;
            etc...  
        }
    }
} else {
    other stuff.. etc..
    $DBH = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

I've gotten simple select statements to work fine as this user (I don't think its permission-related), my problem seems to be with my implementation of PDO. How can I get rid of this error? Am I preparing/executing the statement in a weird way that's messing this up? Thanks for any help

Comment: Well it seems like you're certainly able to connect as well since the exception is occurring during the call to setFetchMode.  Have you tried just a simple mysql_connect & mysql_connect just as a sanity check?  (As a side note looks like they're discouraging those methods now, I'm getting to old for this, lol!)

Comment: try with your root user. If you can run the queries with that one, then it is permissions. I had a similar issue, all seemed fine, but then some queries were not running right with the ddbb user.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  After I uploaded my code from local to production server, and the user had all privileges.  The problem was the database name -- in my local environment it was something like dattabase1 and in production the name was different...prefix_ddatabas1.  I changed the name of the database to the correct one and everything was ok.

Comment: _facepalm_ ... sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an access issue on the server:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command
>   denied to user '...'@'205.186.180.26' for table 'invited'

Have you tested from the CLI (or some other sql client outside of PHP) to ensure your script will have access?

You will likely need to log into the db to give access to a user your script is running as or check the credentials you're using in the script are accurate for the db in the server environment.

Comment: I don't think so.. I've made sure this user has the right permissions, I can execute queries no problem with simpler php scripts and from phpmyadmin. I edited my question to add that, thanks!

Comment: @Alan: Well you can have different permissions for different tables, and if it was only a syntax error you would most likely get a different message with direction of where in the query you have gone wrong. So i would try the **exact same** query from a mysql client jsut to be sure before moving forward.

Comment: the query works though if I run it in phpMyAdmin and replace the variable with an actual value.

Comment: How about trying this query just to ensure something goofy isn't going on w/ the quote() business `SELECT * FROM mydbname.invited LIMIT 1`

Comment: This worked for me because I only had permission to update, but not select, on Webmin.  Changed permissions to all and now I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, code working at dev server but not at prod server, and other scripts working with same table were working. I had missed to correct database table prefixes between dev and prod environment. (the database's names were not the same) ^^

Comment: In my case I had two databases with a different user for each one. As my framework (Laravel 5) was creating a JOIN from two databases, I had to authorize both users in each of two databases used in the JOIN operation.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. The dev DB name was different than the production DB name thus causing this error. I changed the name of the db in my code to the production DB name and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You have an access violation:

```
Syntax error or access violation
```

The user/host you're using:

```
1142 SELECT command denied to user '...'@'205.186.180.26'
```

can not select from the table 'invited'

Comment: I can read the error too! :) But - I don't think it's a permission problem. I can run queries no problem as this user in other scripts and through phpMyAdmin. Is there something besides permissioning that would cause this error? Maybe the bit about the syntax?

Comment: Don't see anything, sorry.  Confirm you can select * from that db.table?